# Action Notification: both UIUserNotificationActionBehavior.TextInput and Button on Banner

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, notifications

I would like to display two possible actions: One text input UIUserNotificationActionBehavior.TextInput, and the other one as a normal action, which looks like a button.

If I use only one of them it works fine, but as soon as I use the two of them it's broken as a notification banner (unlocked screen): only the button is presented, and once I click on it the TextInput appears.

Is it possible to have both of them as the same time on the banner ?

This is my code:

```
    let replyAction : UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    replyAction.identifier = "REPLY"
    replyAction.title = "Reply"
    replyAction.behavior = UIUserNotificationActionBehavior.TextInput
    replyAction.destructive = false
    replyAction.authenticationRequired = false
    replyAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background

    let defaultReplyAction : UIMutableUserNotificationAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    defaultReplyAction.identifier = "DEFAULT_REPLY"
    defaultReplyAction.title = "Default"
    defaultReplyAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
    defaultReplyAction.authenticationRequired = false
    defaultReplyAction.destructive = false

    let notificationMessageCategory : UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    notificationMessageCategory.identifier = "MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
    notificationMessageCategory.setActions([replyAction, defaultReplyAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
    notificationMessageCategory.setActions([replyAction, defaultReplyAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: NSSet(array: [notificationMessageCategory]) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```